# How to generate MongoDB entities with JDL with @DBRef annotation in Jhipster

Tags: mongodb, jhipster, spring-data-mongodb, jdl

I'm trying to generate MongoDB entities with [jdl-studio](http://www.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/)
and I need to define @DBRef annotation for one entity which is related to another.
I couldn't find any information in documentation so I hope you can help me.
Let's suppose we have two entities, I need Country to have a field list of Region IDs

```
entity Region {
   regionName String
}
entity Country {
    countryName String
}
```

Comment: NoSQL Relationships are not supported by JHipster.  You will need to make manual changes to the generated code.

Comment: @JonRuddell Yes looks like there is no other way. I shall do it manually. Thank you